# Laravel URL redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

my project url is
http://localhost/starmaker/admin

site works fine but when i add an extra slash to the url it redirect the site to localhost

like this
http://localhost/starmaker/admin/            (i added an extra slash after admin) and hit enter

http://localhost/admin

I want the url should be 
http://localhost/starmaker/admin

.htaccess and index.php is placed in root directory not in public folder

**HTACCESS CODE**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# block files which needs to be hidden // in here specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock|example)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# in here specify full file name sperator '|'
<Files ~ "(artisan)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

**ROUTING CODE**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $login_user_id = \Session::get('id');
    if (isset($login_user_id) || $login_user_id != "") {
        Redirect::to('user/profile')->send();
    } 
    else {
        return View::make('frontend.welcome');
    }
});

Route::get('admin', function () {
    return View::make('backend.adminlogin');
});

Route::controller('admin',                  'adminController');
```

Comment: this is not enough info, how is your route file setup??

Comment: ROUTE FILE 
------------------------------------------------------- 
Route::get('/', function () {
    $login_user_id = \Session::get('id');
    if (isset($login_user_id) || $login_user_id != "") {
        Redirect::to('user/profile')->send();
    } 
    else {
        return View::make('frontend.welcome');
    }
});

Route::get('admin', function () {
    return View::make('backend.adminlogin');
});

Route::controller('admin',                  'adminController');

Comment: your choice to use Route::controller is very interesting. What version of laravel is this?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.4, it can also be used in larvel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little change in the `.htaccess` file in public directory

Find the following lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

and remove them or add hash `#` in the beginning like below to comment it.

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
#RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: try it after cleaning the cache

Comment: or run it in a private window of the browser

Comment: i know its a htaccess issue, because i've faced the exactly same issue many times, but changes in the htaccess file do not reflect in the browser without cleaning the browser cache